# Android: POP3-only email clients without mandatory SMTP settings?

Tags: email

I have a few email accounts at a free email service (and all accounts are old but I prefer to use them as non-primary), and I'd like to connect them to my Android email client. In free mode, that email service only allows POP3 access so I use that for registering at message boards, services etc for really long time. When I was trying to add those accounts to my Android email client, I failed to do that because my client also requires SMTP settings. Sure, as a work around, I can use Gmail to import those accounts to my primary Gmail, but I'd like to keep them separated.

So, the question is: is there an Android email client that does not require mandatory SMTP access?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: questions about mobile devices are off topic on superuser, have a look at the faq. better have the question migrated to android.SE.

Comment: @WalterMaier-Murdnelch oops, I was not aware of Android StackExchange. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, but please do not repost your question there, wait for migration :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it myself:

[K-9 Mail @ Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fsck.k9&hl=uk)